# Можно ли совершить DDoS атаку с помощью клавиши F5?

Tags: сервер

Можно ли совершить простейшую DDoS 
атаку с помощью клавиши F5? Просто ради интереса, никаких серьезных намерений.

Comment: Разве что DoS. На некоторых сайтах, особенно у банков, можно попасть в бан от анти-DoS фильтра. Для D-DoS нужно несколько таких экспериментаторов.

Comment: Товарищ Чжан Сань говорит что легко :)

Comment: Совершить такую атаку можно, но только на самого себя :)